# Как использовать хуки внутри jest тестов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest

Я недавно начал изучать Jest и никак не могу понять, как использовать хуки в тестах Jest. Суть в том, что не работают именно React хуки. При помещении хука в 'name.test.tsx' выдает ошибку :

```
useSubmitAuthor > 1
-----
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')Jest
```

Хотя я не уверен правильно ли так делать

код useInputChange.tsx :

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

function useInputChange(setText: (text: string) => void) {
  if (setText) {
    return {
      onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setText(event.target.value),
    };
  }

  return { onChange: () => {} };
}

export default useInputChange;
```

код useInputChange.text.tsx :

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

describe('useInputChange', () => {
  it('1', () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('') // тут ошибка
    expect(text).toBe('')
    
    render(
      <div>
        <input type="text" data-testid="input" />
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: К сожалению этим не занимался, но гугл рекомендует мне это первым https://blog.logrocket.com/test-react-hooks/

Comment: А ещё у вас в файле ошибки нет `import React from "react";`

Comment: @EzioMercer Если вы про useInputChange.tsx, то нет, это хук. Там ```import React from "react";``` не нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хук нужно передать коллбэком в renderHook() а setState() в act()

renderHook() и act() импортируются из `@testing-library/react`

Было:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

describe('useInputChange', () => {
  it('1', () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('') // тут ошибка
    expect(text).toBe('')
    
    render(
      <div>
        <input type="text" data-testid="input" />
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
});
```

Стало:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {
  render, renderHook, act
} from '@testing-library/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

describe('useInputChange', () => {
  it('1', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useState(''));
    const [text, setText] = result.current;
    act(() => setText('123123'));
    expect(result.current[0]).toBe('123123');

    render(
      <div>
        <input type="text" data-testid="input" />
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
});
```

[Источник: https://itchef.ru/articles/99719/](https://itchef.ru/articles/99719/)